# Cannot update text element using javascript. When button is clicked text returns to previous value

Tags: javascript

## UPDATE/SOLUTION

Hey Folk!
Thnx to all that previously provided some info to resolve this challenge.  Lastnite, I decided to tackle this again, yea after more than a year LOL.  Well the answer came fairly quickly.  Turns out that the site required an event trigger that validates the input before it continues the process after the submit 'action' is envoked.  Now, in my current setup I had to PASTE the new text value and then have the javacript do its job, this is not ideal since the operation can happen more than 100 times or more per day. 
 **Then the light buble came on!   Lets have javascript, instead of me, execute a paste command!**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('input-number')[0].value = ""; //clear input
document.getElementsByClassName('input-number')[0].focus(); //set focus
document.execCommand('insertText', false, '0.0000003');  // 'paste' new text value
```

Of course '0.0000003' will be a variable :).

That did the job!!! The code can now change the text, click on the submit button and the new text is used!  Hope this helps others with similar issue.

Take care,
Jess

PS: Yes, I know execCommand() is obsolete, will update that later.. for now it works fine.

===============================================================

I am trying to update text element and then click a button using java script but have no luck with the value of the text element being the value that I programmed.  It reverts back to the value that was on the element before.

The website in question is: https://betfury.io/dapps/dice

Code Snippets:

```
//first set text to x value
document.getElementsByClassName('inp-number')[0].value=0.000001
    
//Then I click on the button to start the game
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn_blue btn_large')[2].click();
```

When the scripts are executed you can see the change and the button clicked but after the click, the text value returns to what it was before and not the 0.000001 value I want it to be.

Please advice.

Comment: We need a minimum reproducible example. Also, this is a terrible way of selecting elements, please use ID instead.

Comment: the link in the question looks suspicious to me

Comment: @lastr2d2  the site is legit.  I have successfully withdrawn BTC gains etc etc.   thnx for the comment :)

Comment: @ Micheal.    These are the essential pieces of code that I require for it to operate.  If you want me to provide my source, I can do that but I will water it down cause it is quite extensive.  I cannot use the ID element for the html code does not provide this, they only provide the Class name.   The real issue is as I say.  I set everything and when I click on the "GO" button the text element is returned back to its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about page that linked by you, But maybe you want set value of Web-game.

Generally, Element value of Web-game is just display value, and real value stored in other data store. For example, Local Storage, Local Variable, Server Database...

I recommend try debugger to know "How this game works". Then maybe you can cheating that game.

Comment: at HOTO...  Great idea. You may be on to somthing.  I will do an examination of any variables that are stored in local storage.   Thanks

Comment: @user15127088 You may approve my answer If it helped.